# I created a point class to use in a HashSet but the contains function doesn't work

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean canFinish(int numCourses, int[][] prerequisites) {
        HashSet<Point> set = new HashSet<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < prerequisites.length; i++) {
            int x = prerequisites[i][0];
            int y = prerequisites[i][1];
            if (set.contains(new Point(x,y))) {
                return false;
            }
            set.add(new Point(x,y));
            if (set.contains(new Point(x,y))) {
                return false;
            }
            set.add(new Point(y,x));
        }
        System.out.println(set);
        return true;
    }
    
    class Point {
        int x;
        int y;
        
        Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        
    }
}
```

It never returns false. Any ideas why this is happening? I intentionally added two contains functions to see if it would returns false, but it never does.

Comment: Because your set will never already contain the brand new Point you're creating?  If you want it to compare the *values* contained in a Point, you need to tell it how to do that (i.e. implement hashcode and equals).

Comment: An easy way to solve the issue (in modern versions of Java) is to convert the `Point` to a record: `record Point(int x, int y) { }`

Comment: If it is the same object (with the same memory address on the heap) for the contains judgment, you will get the correct result. If you need to judge whether it is included according to the fields of the object, you need to implement the `hashcode()` and `equals()` method. The hashmap does not know what fields you need to judge whether it is the same object. By default,  it will judge whether the memory addresses of the two objects are the same.